# Outgassing at $10^{-7}$ Torr

Tags: magnetic-fields, vacuum

I have two iron bars in a vacuum of $10^{-7}$ Torr. One is highly magnetized and the other is not. Will outgassing from the magnetized bar be less than the outgassing from the non-magnetized bar? Essentially what I'm asking, will the magnetic forces in the magnetized bar prevent gaps from occurring in the bar due to magnetic forces holding the material more tightly together?

Comment: It is doubtful. The densities of the two bars are the same. Doesn't this prove that "magnetic forces" do not significantly change the forces between atoms in a metal? Indeed the forces that hold together a solid crystal are A LOT stronger than the magnetic force between atoms in a permanent magnet. Also if you have two iron bars next to eachother and one is highly magnetized, the other will be soon.

Comment: @AXensen - if magnetic energy could be ignored, iron would be an hcp crystal at room temperature, not bcc. But, you are correct that there are no 'gaps' being closed by the magnetic interactions. There may be more subtle issues depending on just what is outgassing but major impurities such as H, C, and O do not have magnetic interaction terms in the thermodynamics of Fe phases.

Comment: @JonCuster I guess that's true. Given that the Curie temperature is comparable to the melting temperature, it must take significant energy to destroy the magnetism. But in that sense actually the two bars are the same. Just the "unmagnetized" iron bar doesn't have its domains aligned.